# Webtest with Selenium - together? Possible? How?

Tags: python, selenium, webtest

While reading through [WebTest documentation](http://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), I found a somehow cryptic note about [webtest.http.StopableWSGIServer](http://webtest.pythonpaste.org/en/2.0.5/http.html):

> StopableWSGIServer is a WSGIServer which run in a separated thread. This allow to use tools like casperjs or selenium.

I know, what [WebTest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebTest) does. It is a package to simulate a web browser, with a very nice API, to test web pages.

I know, what [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) does. It is a package that allows a programmer to actually use a real web browser to test web pages.

I use both of those tools in my codebase, only separately.

Somehow I can get my head around the thought of using WebTest *with* Selenium.

Could anybody please elaborate on that? Am I missing something?

My first idea, a bit vague, is to use WebTest API to access pages running inside a browser controller by Selenium. Was it the idea behind [webtest-selenium package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webtest-selenium/)?

As a side note, [webtest-selenium package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webtest-selenium/) seems to be in very early stage of development, since a long time. Does anybody know, is it alive?